# Drupal 7 - Organic groups - departamental views

Tags: drupal-7, organic-groups

I need this functionality:

1 different departments on a node (content type)
2 the content created by a deparment can only be seen-edit-created by a user in the department
3 I need some users that will be on different departments so they can see-edit content on different departments
4 I need a place where all this nodes can be seen (every user will see only the one from their deparments.
5 I need to map on a leaflet map the nodes but a user only will see in the map their deparment´s nodes.

can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure if a got you, so I'm going to ask you a couple things: 1. WHy you don't create many deparments content types as you need and each deparment will be a group?. 2. Add any user you want to each department. 3. A user could be in multiple departments at the same time. 4. Create an og view. 50 Not sure what you mean. I hope this help, but the question will be more clear with a diagram or any image.

Comment: I need only one content type to use leaflet Maps.

Comment: Yes you'r rigth. But with one content type you can create many contents (deparments) as you need.